# What is while(n- - >1)meaning?

Tags: javascript

I saw a [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-and-say/) in leetcode.

Also,I found solution in it.

And one thing i don't understand is this line of code

```
 while(n-- >1)
```

Could someone explain --> meaning?
Here is the JS:

```js
 var countAndSay = function(n) {
    var result = "1";

    var prev;
    var count;
    var tmp;

    while (n-- > 1) {
        prev = result[0];
        count = 1;
        tmp = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (prev === result[i]) {
                count++;
            } else {
                tmp.push(count, prev);
                prev = result[i];
                count = 1;
            }
         }
    
         tmp.push(count, prev);
         result = tmp.join("");
       }

    return result;
     };
    console.log(countAndSay(4))
```

One last thing,Could someone explain what is this question's meaning.

I still don't understand why 2 is 11,3 is 21,4 is 1211 and 5 is 111221.

Comment: The expression is evaluated as `(n--) > 1`. `n` is decreased by one and the result is compared against `1`. As for what the question is about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: @FelixKling just to be clear n-- > 1 compares n and 1 first then decreases n by 1

Comment: @ChrisLi: Yes and no. `n--` returns the old value of `n`, so we use the old value for the comparison, but `n` is still decreased before the comparison. But my comment is certainly lacking that information.

Comment: _I still don't understand why 2 is 11,3 is 21,4 is 1211 and 5 is 111221._ That's the whole essence of the question. See the hints in the question to understand. The answer to that holds the key to getting the solution. So, try to read the question again and the hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
n-- > 1
```

means: subtract one from `n`, and check whether its value *before* the subtraction was greater than 1.

```
while (n-- > 1) {
  // rest of the code
```

is equivalent to

```
while (true) {
  if (n > 1) {
    n--;
    // rest of the code
  } else {
    // n is decremented regardless:
    n--;
    // initial condition was not fulfilled:
    break;
  }
```

Or, with the negation of the condition:

```
while (true) {
  const origN = n;
  n--;
  if (!(origN > 1)) {
    break;
  }
  // rest of the code
```

Comment: I have a query here, the comparison is made with the decremented value of n or the value is decremented after comparison?

Comment: The comparison is made with the value before the subtraction; the value is decremented after subtraction, like in the last code block.

Comment: *"the value is decremented after subtraction"*... I believe you meant "the value is decremented after comparison".

Comment: No worries. Regarding your answer, you wrote `if (n > 1) break;`, but shouldn't it be `if (n <= 1) break`, or even `if (n === 1) break`?

Answer (score 0):

That means you check whether the n is greater than 1 and after that decrement n by 1.

Answer (score 0):

That means, subtract 1 from `n` and check if the result is greater than 1.

`n--` in any part of the code is equivalent to `n = n - 1`, or ``n -= 1`, in that loop is a consised way to subtract and evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(n-- > 1)` is similar to comparing the value of `n` greater than 1. But the thing which **you must notice** is the value of **n will not be decremented(at the beginning) while comparing here**. This is because the value of n is first compared with 1 after that only, the value of n is decremented. To understand this clearly, you can take a look over this.

```js
function test(name) {
  var n = 5;
  while (n-- == 5) { //Here the decrement doesn't takes places so it gets inside the block
    console.log(n); //This statement returns the value of n as 4.
  }
}
const testing = new test();
```